# Classes: How to make it so that the user can input a dictionary into my class?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, typeerror

I need to edit my code so rather than creating the bag dictionary myself below, instead the user can input their own dictionary. A doc test of this would go as:

```
>>> bag = BeadBag({'green':44, 'blue':20, 'yellow':15, 'red':11, 'white':2, 'black':1})
>>> bag.draw()
'yellow'
>>> bag.replace('yellow')
```

The user would be inputting the dictionary into their call and I would no longer need "bag".

Also I randomly keep getting

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

or

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

every now and then when I try running this code.

The doc test that I am personally running just for looking over my work is:

```
>>>bag = BeadBag()
>>>bag.draw()
'black'
>>>bag.replace('yellow')
{'red': [11], 'yellow': 23, 'green': [33], 'blue': [44], 'white': [55], 'black': 65}
```

But it's not quite what I need it to be.

```
import random
class BeadBag(object):
    """
    >>> bag = BeadBag({'green':44, 'blue':20, 'yellow':15, 'red':11, 'white':2, 'black':1})
    >>> bag.draw()
    'yellow'
    >>> bag.replace('yellow')
    >>>
    """
    bag = {'red':[11], 'yellow':[22], 'green':[33], 'blue':[44], 'white':[55], 'black':[66]}

    def draw(self):

        words = []
        for i in BeadBag.bag.keys():
            words.append(i)
        rand = random.choice(words)
        minus = ((BeadBag.bag.get(rand))[0]-1) #subtracts one from each draw
        for key, value in BeadBag.bag.items():
            BeadBag.bag[rand] = minus
        return rand

    def replace(self, color):
        cvalue = (BeadBag.bag[color])
        for i in cvalue:
            val = int(i)
        add = val+1
        for key, value in BeadBag.bag.items():
            BeadBag.bag[color] = add
        return BeadBag.bag
```

Comment: What should the `draw` method do? It seems to only decrement  `1` from a random item on `bag`. Is that it?

Comment: Also, the `replace` method seems to be only incrementing `1` in the given `color` in `bag`.

Comment: You are initializing each value in the dictionary to a *list*, for example '[33]'.  But your function draw replaces it with a *simple integer* in the statement `BeadBag.bag[rand] = minus`.  After that you can no longer access the value using list syntax like `BeadBag.bag.get(rand))[0]` because the `[0]` means "first element of the list".  That fails if the object isn't a list.

Comment: Why is `bag` a class attribute instead of an instance attribute? Do you really want all instances of the `BeadBag` class sharing and performing operation on the same dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

When defining your class, you need to provide an `__init__` function. This will take arguments that are the items provided to the class when you create it.

```
class BeadBag():
    def __init__(self, input_dictionary):
        self.bag = input_dictionary
```

Comment: And how does that help OP, specifically? You may want to elaborate a little.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `self` to denote your class instead of `BeadBag` inside your class.

start from here.

```
import random


class BeadBag(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
        self.words = d.keys()

    def draw(self):
        rand = random.choice(self.words)
        #self.d will be your dict. do whatever you want.

    def replace(self, color):
        cvalue = self.d[color]
        # rest of the code.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to accomplish with your class, this may do it:

```
import random


class BeadBag(object):
    """
    >>> bag = BeadBag({'green':44, 'blue':20, 'yellow':15, 'red':11, 'white':2, 'black':1})
    >>> bag.draw()
    'yellow'
    >>> bag.replace('yellow')
    >>>
    """

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.bag = d

    def draw(self):
        rand = random.choice([k for k in self.bag.keys()])
        minus = self.bag.get(rand) - 1
        self.bag[rand] = minus

        return rand

    def replace(self, color):
        self.bag[color] += 1
```

sample usage:

```
>>> bag = BeadBag({'green':44, 'blue':20, 'yellow':15, 'red':11, 'white':2, 'black':1})
>>> bag.draw()
'red'
>>> bag.bag
{'green': 44, 'blue': 20, 'yellow': 15, 'red': 10, 'white': 2, 'black': 1}
>>> bag.replace('red')
>>> bag.bag
{'green': 44, 'blue': 20, 'yellow': 15, 'red': 11, 'white': 2, 'black': 1}
```

I assumed you meant to store the `bag` dictionary on an instance attribute rather than a class one (which is shared with all instances).

The `draw` method decrements `1` from a random key in `bag` and returns the decremented key.

The `replace` method simply increments `1` from the `bag[color]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to the dictionary to be specified when instance of the `BeadBag` class are created and each one will have it's own `bag` dictionary attribute.

This still doesn't pass the doctest, but that because there are issues in both the `draw)` and `replace()` methods that have nothing to do with the question you've asked — and it's unclear to me exactly what you were trying to do in them, so they still need fixing.

```
import ast
import doctest
import random

class BeadBag(object):
    """
    >>> bag = BeadBag("{'green':44, 'blue':20, 'yellow':15, 'red':11, 'white':2, 'black':1}")
    >>> bag.draw()
    'yellow'
    >>> bag.replace('yellow')
    >>>
    """

    def __init__(self, string):
        self.bag = ast.literal_eval(string)
        assert isinstance(self.bag, dict)

    def draw(self):
        words = []
        for i in self.bag.keys():
            words.append(i)
        rand = random.choice(words)
        minus = ((self.bag.get(rand))[0]-1) #subtracts one from each draw
        for key, value in self.bag.items():
            self.bag[rand] = minus
        return rand

    def replace(self, color):
        cvalue = (self.bag[color])
        for i in cvalue:
            val = int(i)
        add = val+1
        for key, value in self.bag.items():
            self.bag[color] = add
        return self.bag

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
```